# I can't delete cases from .sav files using spss with python

Tags: python, spss

I have some .sav files that I want to check for bad data. What I mean by bad data is irrelevant to the problem. I have written a script in python using the spss module to check the cases and then delete them if they are bad. I do that within a datastep by defining a dataset object and then getting its case list. I then use

```
del datasetObj.cases[k]
```

to delete the problematic cases within the datastep.

Here is my problem:

Say I have a data set foo.sav  and it is the active data set in spss, then I can run something like:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
spss.StartDataStep()
datasetObj = spss.Dataset()
caselist = datasetObj.cases
del caselist[k]
spss.EndDataStep()
END PROGRAM.
```

from within the spss client and it will delete the case k from the data set foo.sav. But, if I run something like the following using the directory of foo.sav as the working directory:

```
import os, spss

pathname = os.curdir()

foopathname = os.path.join(pathname, 'foo.sav')

spss.Submit("""
GET FILE='%(foopathname)s'.
DATASET NAME file1.
DATASET ACTIVATE file1.
""" %locals())

spss.StartDataStep()
datasetObj = spss.Dataset()
caselist = datasetObj.cases
del caselist[3]
spss.EndDataStep()
```

from command line, then it doesn't delete the case k. Similar code which gets values will work fine. E.g.,

```
print caselist[3]
```

will print case k (when it is in the data step). I can even change the values for the various entries of a case. But it will not delete cases. Any ideas?

I am new to python and spss, so there may be something that I am not seeing which is obvious to others; hence why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first piece of code did not work for me. I adjusted it as follows to get it working:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
spss.StartDataStep()
datasetObj = spss.Dataset()
del datasetObj.cases[k]
spss.EndDataStep()
END PROGRAM.
```

Notice that, in your code, `caselist` is just a list, containing values taken from the datasetObj in SPSS. The attribute `.cases` belongs to `datasetObj`.

With `spss.Submit`, you can also delete cases (or actually, not select them) using the SPSS command `SELECT IF`. For example, if your file has a variable (column) named `age`, with values ranging from 0 to 100, you can delete all cases with an age lower than (in SPSS: `lt` or `<`) 25 using:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
spss.Submit("""
SELECT IF age lt 25.
""")
END PROGRAM.
```

Don't forget to add some code to save the edited file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and pointing out that there was an error in the code. Sadly, that wasn't causing the problem in my original code. The issue I have is with running the second block of code. It doesn't actually delete the case, but I don't know why. I also added some code to save the file after deleting the case when running some tests,, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Oh wait, I overlooked your use of the string replacement. Please see http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html

Answer (score 0):

caselist is not actually a regular list containing the dataset values.  Although its interface is the list interface, it actually works directly with the dataset, so it does not contain a list of values.  It just accesses operations on the SPSS side to retrieve, change, or delete values.  The most important difference is that since Statistics is not keeping the data in memory, the size of the caselist is not limited  by memory.

However, if you are trying to iterate over the cases with a loop using
range(spss.GetCaseCount())
and deleting some, the loop will eventually fail, because the actual case count reflects the deletions, but the loop limit doesn't reflect that.  And datasetObj.cases[k] might not be the case you expect if an earlier case has been deleted.  So you need to keep track of the deletions and adjust the limit or the k value appropriately.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wasn't really concerned about the changing case list, I really just want to make a for loop which loops over the cases, so the case indices won't matter in the end. My problem is with trying to get my second block of code above to delete the case. Thanks again.

Comment: The del command should delete case 3 in the code above, but an alternative would be to generate a new 0/1 variable flagging the cases to be deleleted and applying SELECT IF.